# how to break a long line of chained assignments in python

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

I have a long line of chained assignments like this:

```
long_variable_name = another_long_name = a_third_name = some_func()
```

I'd like to break it without using the line continuation character `\`. Typically I do this by using extra parenthesis, e.g.

```
result = (some_long_func(), some_other_long_func(), some_third_func(),
          some_fourth_func())
```

I can't see how to parenthesize chained assignments, since these are not valid syntax:

```
a = b = (c = 1)
a = b = c (= 1)
```

Is there any way to break a long line of chained assignments without using the line continuation character?

Comment: This seems to be a contradiction in terms: you want to continue the line, but without using Python's line continuation syntax.  Why are you trying to avoid the language facility provided for exactly this purpose?

Comment: Parentheses don't work because that's the syntax to create a sub-expression (second attempt) or a tuple (first attempt).

Comment: @Prune I guess you could say Python is inconsistent with its own design principles (preferring implicit vs explicit here) but to quote PEP8 "The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation."

Comment: I don't see an inconsistency, but I see your point as a user.  The language definition gives us priorities for how to continue a line.  "Compound statement" doesn't fit either of those.  However, I don't (yet) understand why you want a paired enclosure to the exclusion of the end-of-line continuation.  From the user view, I can argue "your" side more readily than the existing implementation.  From the parser's side, I can better argue the designers' standpoint -- the syntactic space is crowded at that point in the grammar.

Comment: No profound reasoning here :) I just read that paragraph in PEP8 a few years ago, and haven't needed a line continuation character since! Since this was the first time I thought I might need one, I wanted to check whether I was missing a way of spanning mulitple lines without `\` in my example. The answer is a definitive "no" so I'm happy, and I think the accepted answer outlines the choices quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a single statement, there are no subexpressions to parenthesize. I'm not a fan of explicit line continuations, but this is probably a case where it looks least bad (maybe because the variables names are still probably shorter than other lines you might be breaking).

```
long_variable_name = \
    another_long_name = \
    a_third_name = some_func()
```

I don't know if you would want to put the function call on a line by itself or not.

If you really want to avoid explicit line breaking, I'd recommend not chaining the assignments in the first place.

```
long_variable_name = some_func()
another_long_name = long_variable_name
a_third_name = long_variable_name
```

You might try tuple unpacking. It looks a bit hackish IMO, but ...

```
(long_variable_name,
 another_long_name,
 a third_name) = (some_func(),)*3
```

At the cost of a little more runtime overhead, you could use `itertools.repeat`:

```
from itertools import repeat

(long_variable_name,
 another_long_name,
 a third_name) = repeat(some_func(), 3)
```

although both approaches make you specify the number of variables being assigned too. Although you can capture the remainder of a *finite* sequence in a catch-all variable during tuple unpacking, I'm not aware of a similar trick for infinite sequences.

```
# Good
v1, v2, v3, *rest = repeat(some_func(), 100)

# Bad - infinite loop
v1, v2, v3, *rest = repeat(some_func())
```

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a cleaner way to do this!